# New to GitHub - Error when pushing to a repository

Tags: github

When I commit my changes and attempt to Sync / Push to my github repository, I get the following error:

HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
cannot spawn askpass: No such file or directory
could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
Pushing to https://github.com//ComicBookGallery

I am using VS2017 Community, and using the Github for VS Extension. I've googled this error but have been unable to solve. Running VS in administrator mode makes no difference,

Any ideas?

(I am logged into GitHub within VS, and can log into my account fine on github.com)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went to the repository and searched for this issue, found [this issue from today](https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/issues/1503), where user [@meaghanlewis](https://github.com/meaghanlewis) states:

> Today GitHub turned off TLSV1.1 in order to permanently disable deprecation of several weak cryptographic standards. You could read more about that here: https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/.
>
> To fix this issue, you should upgrade to the latest version of Visual Studio, 15.5.7- which provides support for TLSV1.2. This update allows Git to connect to services that have deprecated support for TLSv1 and TLSv1.1.
>
> You might also need to sign in (or sign out and then sign back in) using GitHub for Visual Studio.

User @barsonax replied stating that upgrading it to 15.5.7 fixed it.

Hope this helps, but it's better to continue seeking help for this issue directly on the issue.

Comment: Great. No admin rights - no sysadmin wide and far - and i should WORK...